# python pandas pivot_table count frequency in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am still new to Python pandas' `pivot_table` and would like to ask a way to count frequencies of values in one column, which is also linked to another column of ID. The DataFrame looks like the following.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Account_number':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
                   'Product':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','A', 'B']
                  })
```

For the output, I'd like to get something like the following:

```
                Product
                A      B
Account_number           
      1         2      0
      2         1      2
      3         1      1
```

So far, I tried this code:

```
df.pivot_table(rows = 'Account_number', cols= 'Product', aggfunc='count')
```

This code gives me the two same things. What is the problems with the code above? A part of the reason why I am asking this question is that this DataFrame is just an example. The real data that I am working on has tens of thousands of account_numbers.

Comment: All the answers on this page will not work for DataFrames with more than 3 columns. The idiomatic solution is to use `aggfunc='size'`. [See my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52906833/3707607) for more details

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to specify the `aggfunc` as `len`:

```
In [11]: df.pivot_table(index='Account_number', columns='Product', 
                        aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
Out[11]:
Product         A  B
Account_number
1               2  0
2               1  2
3               1  1
```

*It looks like count, is counting the instances of each column (`Account_number` and `Product`), it's not clear to me whether this is a bug...*

Comment: @Andy_Hayden, +1. I don't think it's a bug, but I would wish the behavior to be more consistent, see: `df.pivot_table(rows='Account_number', cols='Product', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)`

Comment: @CTZhu I think it might be a bug (you don't expect the used columns to be included in the aggregation, in fact they make no sense with sum!)

Comment: `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Answer (score 47):

**Solution:** Use `aggfunc='size'`

Using `aggfunc=len` or `aggfunc='count'` like all the other answers on this page will not work for DataFrames with more than three columns. By default, pandas will apply this `aggfunc` to all the columns not found in `index` or `columns` parameters.

For instance, if we had two more columns in our original DataFrame defined like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Account_number':[1, 1, 2 ,2 ,2 ,3 ,3], 
                   'Product':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','A', 'B'], 
                   'Price': [10] * 7,
                   'Quantity': [100] * 7})
```

Output:

```
   Account_number Product  Price  Quantity
0               1       A     10       100
1               1       A     10       100
2               2       A     10       100
3               2       B     10       100
4               2       B     10       100
5               3       A     10       100
6               3       B     10       100
```

If you apply the current solutions to this DataFrame, you would get the following:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Account_number',
               columns='Product',
               aggfunc=len,
               fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
                  Price    Quantity   
Product            A  B        A  B
Account_number                     
1                  2  0        2  0
2                  1  2        1  2
3                  1  1        1  1
```

#### Solution

Instead, use `aggfunc='size'`. Since `size` always returns the same number for each column, pandas does not call it on every single column and just does it once.

```
df.pivot_table(index='Account_number', 
               columns='Product',
               aggfunc='size',
               fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
Product         A  B
Account_number      
1               2  0
2               1  2
3               1  1
```

Comment: By the way, there's a bug with `margins=True` https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27799

Comment: "By default, pandas will apply this aggfunc to all the columns not found in index or columns parameters." >> this feels like a bug

Comment: Thank you so, so much. This was bothering me for hours until I found your answer.

Answer (score 19):

In new version of Pandas, slight modification is required. I had to spend some time figuring out so just wanted to add that here so that someone can directly use this.

```
df.pivot_table(index='Account_number', columns='Product', aggfunc=len,
               fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `count`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Account_number', columns='Product', aggfunc='count')
```

Comment: Use **`aggfunc='size'`** because 

aggfunc='count' does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is about `pivot_table` but for the problem given in the question, we can use `crosstab`:

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['Account_number'], df['Product'])
```

Output:

```
Product         A  B
Account_number      
1               2  0
2               1  2
3               1  1
```