# Frequency distribution of list against another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to get the frequency distribution of column which is a list of words against the class labels.

```
Label                Numbers
0                    [(a,b,c)]
0                    [(d)]
0                    [(e,f,g)]
1                    [(a,z)]
1                    [(d,x,y)]
```

The output should be:

```
         0          1
a        1          1
b        1          0
c        1          0
d        1          1
e        1          0
f        1          0        
g        1          0
x        0          1
y        0          1
z        0          1
```

Comment: Is your data in `pandas` or some other format?  Your example looks like a `pandas` dataframe, but I don't want to make assumptions.

Comment: @vealkind Yes it is in pandas.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The list of sets in the `'Numbers'` column makes manipulating the DataFrame as-is very difficult (this is not tidy data). The solution is to expand out the DataFrame so that you only have one number in the `'Numbers'` column corresponding to one value in the `'Label'` column. Assuming your data is in a DataFrame called `df`, the following code performs that operation:

```
rows_list = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for element in row['Numbers'][0]:
        dict1 = {}
        dict1.update(key=row['Label'], value=element)
        rows_list.append(dict1)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
new_df.columns = ['Label', 'Numbers']
```

The result is

```
  Label Numbers
0     0     a
1     0     b
2     0     c
3     0     d
4     0     e
5     0     f
6     0     g
7     1     a
8     1     z
9     1     d
10    1     x
11    1     y
```

Now it's a matter of pivoting:

```
print(new_df.pivot_table(index='Numbers', columns='Label', aggfunc=len,
                         fill_value=0))
```

The result is

```
Label    0  1
Numbers      
a        1  1
b        1  0
c        1  0
d        1  1
e        1  0
f        1  0
g        1  0
x        0  1
y        0  1
z        0  1
```

See the [first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412033/python-pandas-pivot-table-count-frequency-in-one-colume) for the last line of code.

Comment: My element is showing `[` only and also the type of element is `string`. I am reading this table from csv file, maybe that's why. Also, I am getting the `Numbers` value from some other function (actually it's a pattern) so I can't change that. But we can process like you have shown.

Comment: @amy: There's a lot in your comment where I don't have any idea what you mean. Hope my code has been helpful!

Comment: I am trying to say the `Numbers` is a string since I am reading the data from csv file. The solution is helpful if it is a list.

Comment: @amy: I see. In that case, you'll need to parse out the string into a list of sets before you can apply the rest of my code. The following code could help with that: `'[(a,b,c)]'.replace('[(', '').replace(')]', '').split(',')` Then you might have to remove the `[0]` part in the inner for loop.