# Get frequncy counts of the values stored in a pandas dataframe column, based on a range, and seperarated by a categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas

### I have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.012343, 'A'], [0.135528, 'A'], [0.198878, 'A'], [0.199999, 'B'], [0.181121, 'B'], [0.199999, 'B']])

df.columns = ['effect', 'category']

     effect          category
0    0.012343        A
1    0.135528        A
2    0.198878        A
3    0.199999        B
4    0.181121        B
5    0.199999        B
```

### My goal is to get a representative of the frequency distribution of each category. In this case, the bin size would be .05. The resulting dataframe would look like the following:

```
 my_distribution = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1, 0, 1, 1], ['B', 0, 0, 0, 3]])

 my_distributions.columns = ['category', '0.0-0.05', '0.05-0.10', 0.1-0.15', '0.15-0.20']

        category  0.0-0.05  0.05-0.10  0.1-0.15  0.15-0.20
0        A         1          0         1          1
1        B         0          0         0          3
```

**____________________________________________________________**

So, in brief what I am trying to do is create bins and count the number of occurrences in each bin, separated by category. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your sample dataframe doesn't match your input: Where is the `[0.99, 'B']`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas pivot\_table count frequency in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412033/python-pandas-pivot-table-count-frequency-in-one-column)

Comment: @G.Anderson Fixed the sample dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) followed by [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) + [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.01, 'A'], [0.13, 'A'], [0.19, 'A'], [0.19, 'B'], [0.18, 'B'], [0.19, 'B']])
df.columns = ['effect', 'category']

labels = ['0.0-0.05', '0.05-0.10', '0.1-0.15', '0.15-0.20']
cuts = df.assign(quant=pd.cut(df.effect, bins=[0.0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20], labels=labels))

# get counts per bin
result = pd.crosstab(cuts.category, columns=cuts.quant)

# reindex with labels to account for bin with 0 counts
result = result.reindex(labels, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)

# reset index and rename axis for display purposes
result = result.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  category  0.0-0.05  0.05-0.10  0.1-0.15  0.15-0.20
0        A         1          0         1          1
1        B         0          0         0          3
```