# Dataframe pivot and grouped by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Having a dataframe:

```
Index | Date        | Code           |
0     | ----------  | -------------- |
1     | 2022-1-1    | A              |
2     | 2022-1-1    | B              |
3     | 2022-1-2    | C              |
4     | 2022-1-3    | A              |
3     | 2022-2-1    | B              |
4     | 2022-2-2    | B              |
```

I want to pivot this so i have  A,B,C as columnns and the amount of Code/day as value
I tried this:

```
df["amount"]=1
df_pivot =pd.pivot_table(df,index=["datum"],columns=["code"],aggfunc = "count")
```

Comment: what `pandas` version are you using?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanx for changing to layout. I'm using 1.2.5

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412033/python-pandas-pivot-table-count-frequency-in-one-column; make sure you have the correct column names for `index` and `columns`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pandas pivot\_table count frequency in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412033/python-pandas-pivot-table-count-frequency-in-one-column)

Comment: That answer was helpfull. So i used '''pd.pivot_table(data=df,index='Date', columns='code', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)''' but is it possible to group the index of a pivot table by quarter year , month ..

Comment: yes, you can generate these columns like this `df['quarter']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.quarter`, similarly, `df['year']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year`, and so on. You don't need `pd.to_datetime` if your `Date` column is already a datetime column. Then, in the index, you can put `index=['quarter', 'year', ...]`

Comment: btw, you should probably update the question or start a new question with your new issue so people can respond in answers rather than comments.

Answer (score -1):

Using your DataFrame example, you can perform a simple pivot with the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2022-1-1","2022-1-1","2022-1-2","2022-1-3","2022-2-1","2022-2-2"],
                   "Code":["A","B","C","A","B","B"]})

pivot = df.pivot(columns="Code",values="Date")
```

With the result being:

```
Code         A         B         C
0     2022-1-1       NaN       NaN
1          NaN  2022-1-1       NaN
2          NaN       NaN  2022-1-2
3     2022-1-3       NaN       NaN
4          NaN  2022-2-1       NaN
5          NaN  2022-2-2       NaN
```

Do you have a desired index or how to handle NAs? If so, refer to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for information on other parameters that might be useful to you.

EDIT: Realized you were asking for a count of code/date combinations. That could be achieved with the following instead:

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(columns="Code",values="Date",aggfunc=len,fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Different from what OP was asking: pivot table with count of Date/Code combinations.

Comment: Hello using pd.pivot_table(data=df,index='datum', columns='code', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0) i have the right pivottable but now i want the index(=date) to change to the year/quarter/month